# Django project, data deleted from the database

Tags: python, django

I am new in web development with Django and MySQL database, I got to develop a web application with Django framework, after deployment of my project in the server.

after 2 months, I noticed that data from my order table was deleted as well as the data of one user is displayed in the profile of another,
I want to know what I must do as a test to know the PR eventual error and to stop the deletion of data in my database.
data often deleted in the order and customer table.

the ORDER model bind with a foreign key to other Model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_('Creation Date'))
    payed = models.DateTimeField( verbose_name=_('Payment Date'), default=datetime.now, null=True, blank=True)
    reference = models.IntegerField( verbose_name=_('Order Reference'), default=0, null=True, blank=True )
    customer = models.ForeignKey( Customers, verbose_name=_('Customer'), null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    company = models.ForeignKey( Compagnie, verbose_name=_('Company'), null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
```

```
class Customers(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Compagnie,
        verbose_name=_('Company'),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    forename = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('First Name'),
        max_length=255,
        null=True,
        blank=True)

    GENDER = [('M', _('Male')),
              ('F', _('Female'))]

    gender = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('Gender'),
        max_length=1,
        choices=GENDER,
        null=True,
        blank=True)

    city = models.ForeignKey(
        City,
        verbose_name=_('City'),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    additionalNum = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('Additional Number:'),
        max_length=60,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    adressCustomer = models.TextField(
        verbose_name=_('Address Customer:'),
        max_length=500,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    telCustomer = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('Phone Customer:'),
        max_length=30,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    emailCustomer = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name=_('Email Customer:'),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    otherBuyerId = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('Other Buyer ID:'),
        max_length=50,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
    vatNumber = models.CharField(
        max_length=120,
        null=True,
        verbose_name=_('Vat Number:'),
        blank=True
    )
    needs_attention = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name=_('Needs attention'),
        default=False)

    biography = models.TextField(
        verbose_name=_('Biography'),
        null=True,
        blank=True)

    _is_updating_cache_fields = False

    def get_name(self):
        first = self.forename or ''
        name = "%s" % (first)
        return name.strip()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Customer')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Customers')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s:  %s' % (
            type(self).__name__,
            self.pk,
            self.forename)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.forename:
             return self.forename
        else:
            return "Unnamed"
```

Can someone give me an explanation for this problem?

Comment: The answer is not going to be in your model, but how you use your model.

Comment: Sorry that I can't tell your problem as it seems to be a bundle of application errors. However, to prevent data being deleted, you could change your foreign key from models.CASCADE to models.SET_NULL to prevent unintended deletion from any update of other tables.

Comment: @Atomyyy, I think this is the source of the problem, I would like to know if for example table 1 link with table2 and table2 link with table3 if i delete record from table1 all data in table2 and table3 will be deleted?

Comment: @SohaibRADI Yes, the foreign key linked record will be deleted because of your on cascade setting